# Is $\{(a,b,c) \in \mathbb{C}^3 | a^3=b^3 \}=S$ a subspace of $\mathbb{C}^3$

Tags: linear-algebra

This is an exercise in Axler's "Linear Algebra Done Right" textbook, and the answer is no, because taking $x=(1,\frac{-1+\sqrt{3}i}{2},0)$ and $y=(1,\frac{-1-\sqrt{3}i}{2},0)$ we have $x+y \notin S$.

Before looking up the answer, I was trying, and failing, to come up with a counterexample. Can someone explain the intuition behind this one? It looks like it was derived somehow.

Comment: $S$ is the union of three hyperplanes, given by $a=b$, $a=\omega b$ and $a=\omega^2b$ where $\omega=\exp(2\pi i/3)$. If you take points from different hyperplanes, it's quite likely their sum is outside $S$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a^3=b^3$, $c^3=d^3$ you want to know if

$$(a+c)^3 =(b+d)^3$$

This is not necessarily the case.

Taking cube-roots in  $\mathbb C$ is a multivalued operation.

$$x^3 = y^3 \iff x=y\sqrt[3]{1}$$

where the cube root is **a** cube root of one. There are three of them.

For intuition, consider the same idea over $\mathbb R^3$ with $a^2=b^2$. Clearly this would not be a subspace because $(1,-1,0)$ and $(1,1,0)$ would belong to this set but their sum, $(2,0,0)$ would not.

Comment: Did you mean cube root of $+1$?

Comment: Yes thank you, shubham